# Piecewise Function Formatting

Tags: spacing, formatting

```
Let $f : \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f(z) = z + \frac{1}{z}$. Given that

$f(z) = \begin{cases} 
\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{n}} &\text{if } z \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace \\
\sqrt{1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}} + i \sqrt{-1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}} &\text{if } z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
 
for some positive integer $n$ and that $f(z^8) = 2023$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace$, find $n$.
```

Here is my latex code for a piecewise function, but the output is just one line, not two lines. How can I make it look like a normal piecewise function? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  (i) on ed equation you not have `$`, (ii) preamble is unknown, so we don't know which relevant package for code fragment you load. PLease extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclaqqss` and ending with `\end{document`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, your equation code is not terminated by `$`. Adding it and extend your code fragment to complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) I got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
Let $f : \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f(z) = z + \frac{1}{z}$. Given that

$
f(z) = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{n}}     & \text{if } z \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace \\
\sqrt{1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}} + i \sqrt{-1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}}
                        & \text{if } z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}
        \end{cases}
$

for some positive integer $n$ and that $f(z^8) = 2023$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace$, find $n$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would write your conditional equation as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document}

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f(z) = z + \frac{1}{z}$. Given that
\[
f(z) = \begin{dcases}
\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{n}}     & \text{if } z \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace \\
\sqrt{1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}} + i \sqrt{-1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}}
                        & \text{if } z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}
\end{dcases}
\]
for some positive integer $n$ and that $f(z^8) = 2023$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace$, find $n$.
\end{document}
```

[image]